# How to Save Data With User Auth id In Table Using Laravel Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

[image: error screenshot]

I have to save data in a database table with userid using laravel ajax. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue

my controller code

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {


        $rearcameras = new Rearcameras();
        $rearcameras->user_id = auth()->id();
        $rearcameras->name = $request->name;
        $rearcameras->size = $request->size;
        $rearcameras->type = $request->type;


        return $this->sendResponse($rearcameras->toArray(), 'Command Send Successfully successfully.');
    }
```

and the response it getting is

```
{"success":true,"data":{"user_id":null,"name":null,"size":null,"type":"f-camera"},"message":"Command Send Successfully successfully."}
```

I have to save logged userId on submitting....I'm getting user_id null how can I store user_id please help me.

[image: usertable screenshot]

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: whrere you save record? add $rearcameras->save();

Comment: @Yasin Patel, I'm saving record using ajax

Comment: $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8000/api/r-camera",
      method: 'post',
      data: $('#frmAddTask').serialize(),
      success: function(response){
            $('#btn-add').html('Submit');
            $('#res_message').show();
            $('#res_message').html(response.msg);
            $('#msg_div').removeClass('d-none');

            document.getElementById("frmAddTask").reset(); 
            setTimeout(function(){
            $('#res_message').hide();
            $('#msg_div').hide();
            },10000);
      }});

Comment: now it gives SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null I have to store logged user id

Comment: can you show your 'user' table structure?

Answer (score 0):

Update your controller code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rearcameras = new Rearcameras();
    $rearcameras->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $rearcameras->name = $request->name;
    $rearcameras->size = $request->size;
    $rearcameras->type = $request->type;
    $rearcameras->save();
    return $this->sendResponse($rearcameras->toArray(), 'Command Send Successfully successfully.');
}
```

Don't forget to use **use Auth** at the top of the controller

Comment: sir thanks for your reply but now I get this message "message": "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "D:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\addspy\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\API\\RearcamerasController.php",
    "line": 42,

Comment: Make sure User should be login

Comment: Yaa it is already logged I'm sending data to the user dashboard @Brij sir

Comment: After that execute this code also check Rearcameras table for data store or not

Comment: no, it's not working sir...again giving the same error

Comment: Ok, Can you send me a screenshot of the user table

Comment: "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null it give this message but I have saved logged Auth Id in database table

Comment: sir post a screenshot of usertable please see and help me solve my issue

Comment: can send me the table structure of user table or you can also send me user table columns name

Comment: table columns name are id, user_id, name, size, image, type

Comment: ok, What here user-id store in user_id so you should use $rearcameras->user_id = Auth::user()->user_id; I update my answer

Comment: sir still getting a  "message": "Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object"

Comment: but I do some chnages I store auth id like this..  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}"> and then save user Id in table and it's working...thanks for helping

Comment: Ok, Please check your user table and make sure user_id should be present in the user  table. and also log out first and then login again

Comment: Ok, great if my answer is helpful for you please accept my answer

Comment: Sir, can you please help me solve one more issue???..."message": "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError", getting this message while storing image but when I post this from postman it works but from the dashboard it gives this message

Comment: file upload is optional if the file is null then default image save.

Comment: sure I will have you try to do